# Is there a way to generate a pdf certificate in WordPress and send to emails

Tags: php, html, database, wordpress, plugins

I wondered if anyone out there could suggest ways of achieving the following.

We run a membership company, and we are relaunching the website using WordPress

We want to do away with the old paper certificates that are sent out to people who make money for our membership as it cost extra money for the paper certificate to be created, printed and sent and more importantly its a waste of paper and ink.

We’d like to create a PDF on the fly with the persons name on it and the membership level paid for in a standard PDF certificate format and then email it to them once their payment has been confirmed.

Does anyone know how we could do that? Interested in your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a WordPress plugin which handles the payment and after the payment is received, the plugin can generate the pdf file from an html template.

I like the tool [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) to create pdf files, because it's one of the easiest ways. But there also exists some php libs, maybe [this post](https://peterdev.pl/2019/01/11/picking-a-php-tool-to-generate-pdfs/) will help.